# Can a map from the disk with exploding phase be smooth at the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, singularity

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be given in polar coordinates by

$\big(r,\theta\big )\mapsto \big(\psi(r),\theta+\phi(r)\big)$, for some smooth **strictly increasing** function $\psi:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ satisfying $\psi(0)=0$ and $\psi'(r)>0$ for all $r$, and a smooth function $\phi:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$.

**Suppose that $\lim_{r \to 0}\phi'(r)\psi(r)$ is finite.** (In particular $\lim_{r \to 0}\phi'(r) = + \infty$ or $\lim_{r \to 0}\phi'(r) = -\infty$).

> **Is it possible** that $f$ is smooth at the origin?

To be clear, I am not asking if **all** such maps are smooth, but whether or not **there exist** such maps that are smooth at the origin.

---

**Edit:**

It would be interesting to know whether the assumption $\psi'>0$ is superfluous.

If $\psi$ goes to zero so quickly, so that all its derivatives vanish at zero, then maybe this implies that $f$ is smooth, even if $\lim_{r \to 0}\phi'(r) = \infty$.

e.g. can we say what happens when
$$
\psi(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2},&\text{if }x\ne 0\\
0,&\text{if }x=0\;,
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Do you want to assume that $\psi'(0)>0$? This is not completely clear from your assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I want to assume that. (Although I am not sure if it really matters, since I also assumed that $\psi$ is strictly increasing-this assumption should rule out trivial examples like the constant zero map).

Comment: I think it matters quite a bit (though I am not sure yet), since you could choose $\psi$ to go to zero so quickly at $0$ that all derivatives vanish at zero, which should (hopefully) suffice to show that your map is smooth. I think I can disprove the existence if $\psi'(0) > 0$; I still need to pin down the details. Note that $\psi'(0) > 0$ is not implied by the strictly increasing property: You could for instance have $\psi(r) = r^2$.

Comment: Hmm... OK, what you say seems very reasonable to me. I think that 
 both cases ($\psi'(0)=0$ and $\psi'(0) \neq 0$ are interesting. I agree that it seems plausible that if $\psi$ goes to zero sufficiently fast, then there might be a chance for the map to be smooth. I would be interested to see the details, if you will manage to work it out. Thanks.