# Can $\psi(x)\cos(\phi(x)),\,\, f_2(x)=\psi(x)\sin(\phi(x))$ be $C^{\infty}$ at zero when $\phi'$ explodes?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, singularity, smooth-functions

The goal of this question is to isolate some aspects of this [geometric question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580453/can-a-map-from-the-disk-with-exploding-phase-be-smooth-at-the-origin).

Let $\psi:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a  smooth strictly increasing function  satisfying $\psi(0)=0$ and let $\phi:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be smooth.

**Suppose that $B:=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\phi'(x)\psi(x)$ is finite.**

Define $$f_1(x)=\psi(x)\cos(\phi(x)), \, \,\,\,f_2(x)=\psi(x)\sin(\phi(x)).$$ $f_i$ are clearly defined on the open interval $(0,\infty)$; we extend them continuously to zero by setting $f_i(x)=0$. (Recall that $\psi(0)=0$).

> Can both the $f_i$ be infinitely (right) differentiable at $x=0$?

So far I managed to derive a necessary condition for the $f_i$ to be $C^1$ at zero, **under the additional assumption that $\psi'(0)>0$.** I am not sure how to proceed to check higher derivatives in a tractable way, or what happens when $\psi'(0)=0$.

> *The necessary condition:* I prove below that we must have $B=0$ and that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \phi(x)$ exists.

Indeed,

$$ \frac{f_1(x)-f_1(0)}{x}=\frac{\psi(x)-\psi(0)}{x}\cos(\phi(x))\Rightarrow \\ \cos(\phi(x))=\frac{f_1(x)-f_1(0)}{x} \frac{1}{\frac{\psi(x)-\psi(0)}{x}} \Rightarrow \\ 
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos(\phi(x))=\frac{f_1'(0)}{\psi'(0)}, $$

and similarly $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(\phi(x))=\frac{f_2'(0)}{\psi'(0)}$.

Thus, both $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos(\phi(x)), \lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(\phi(x))$ exist, and hence so does $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \phi(x)$.

Now, a direct calculation shows that
$$ f_1'(x)=\begin{cases} \psi'(x)\cos(\phi(x))-\psi(x)\phi'(x)\sin(\phi(x)) & \text{if $x > 0$} \\ \psi'(0)\cdot \lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos(\phi(x))  & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}$$

In particular, 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} f_1'(x)=\psi'(0)\cdot \lim_{x \to 0^+}\cos(\phi(x))-B\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(\phi(x))$$

Since we assumed $f_1$ is $C^1$ at zero, we must have $B\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(\phi(x))=0$.

Applying the same considerations for $f_2$, we deduce that $B\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos(\phi(x))=0$. Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ cannot converge both to zero at the same point, we conclude that $B=0$.

Comment: By "explodes", you mean $|\phi'|\to +\infty$?

Comment: Yes. This follows from the assumption that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\phi'(x)\psi(x)$ is finite. (since $\psi(x)$ tends to $\psi(0)=0$ when $x \to 0$).

Comment: That is not true: for example, if we consider $\phi=\sin(1/x)$, it does not satisfies $|\phi'|\to \infty$ (the limit does not exists), yet $\lim_{x\to 0}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\phi'(x)=0$

Comment: An easier counterexample is: $\phi(x)=x$. The limits exists, is finite but $\phi'(x)=1$

Comment: Oh, you are right of course. I was subconsciously thinking on the case where $B=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\phi'(x)\psi(x)$ is non-zero. (Then I think it does imply that $|\phi| \to \infty$, right?). But $B$ can also be zero...still I am interested at the moment in all the possible cases, where $B$ and $\psi'(0)$ can be either zero or non-zero. What I have proved is that $\psi'(0)>0$ forces $B=0$. BTW, I have seen that you deleted your answer. Can  you say what was the problem with it (from a quick glance, it looks fine to me). ? Thanks again for your comments and effort.

Comment: I deleted it by mistake. Let me add that, as PhoemueX wrote on the comment section under your other question, I think, given an effective explosion of the derivative (to avoid the trivial cases like $\phi=x$), the condition $\psi'(0)>0$ is an obstruction to our capacity of extendinf $f_1$ and $f_2$ at $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, without the assumption $\psi'(0)>0$:

$$\psi(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$